# How to get access token for google webmasters api (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, access-token

i need access token for submitting sitemap.
i use passport like so

```
passport.authenticate('googleApi', {scope: ['profile', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters']});
```

and get

```
{ code: '4/aEzOOw1j-1rNCXCVajylMVRasdo2Kasdreisasdradk.MijA9hPKsg8WYFZr95uasdUzab8UkwI' }
```

in request.query

but this token is invalid according to

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=MY_TOKEN
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have got is authorization code.
You have to get access token by exchanging this authorization code.
Read about oauth 2.0 authentication